# Is using a React's Context for form with steps a good idea in general?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

If I have a form with a couple of steps, should I use Context API or state inside of the parent component?

Comment: If state is enough, why to use context. Usually context API used for user preferences like current language or theming. Please check this video by, in which he talks about best use cases [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XaXKiXtNjw). and this from react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context).

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between Context API vs "state in the parent component" is how many levels you have to pass down props (the Provider in context is "state in an ancestor component" rather than a parent component).

So it depends on your component structure. If you have to pass down a callback prop more than one level, I'd go with context.

EDIT: With reference to a comment - your own personal preference comes in play with how far you are willing to [prop drill](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling) for simple state vs context. I don't like doing it **more than** one level. In my opinion (that's a big IMO), it mixes the concerns of a component - you'll end up making a component accept props for the sole purpose of passing them on to child components.

Comment: When you say the only difference between context API vs STATE, do you mean how to use? Because I bet there are a lot more difference into React internals than that.

Comment: Also, I would avoid overuse React Context just to avoid passing props through one level of component. React is design to this usage too, so you should be ok with that. To be more practice, an example, you going to lose a lot of reusability when you create a context, every component inside the context must have the context wraping it

Comment: @ViniciusKatata - the only conceptual difference. The Provider for a specific context will hold values that are almost always part of state somewhere. So, the only difference between context API and state is how you pass the state/state setters (callbacks) down to descendent components - `props` vs `useContext`

Comment: @ViniciusKatata - with regards to your second comment - if I have to "prop drill" **more than** one level deep, I use context. But it's your call, you may be okay with prop drilling three levels or more, it's just not for me.

Comment: Sure, there is not a single and right way to do it, we must choose the trade-off that comprehend our scenario

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question. It depends on your purposes. So, for state management you can use context/ref/state/or library based on FLAX pattern.

I prefer to use context in a lot of situations. If you want to avoid props drilling then the best solution is to use context/ref, but if you have to rerender all your steps then context isn't suitable for you.

Here you can understand all benefits of using context

https://daveceddia.com/context-api-vs-redux/

Comment: I wouldn't use context just to avoid prop drilling, the react team doesn't recomend that, as it says in docs 'If you only want to avoid passing some props through many levels, component composition is often a simpler solution than context.'

Comment: As I already said it depends on purposes. Now it hard to talk without any code. Props drilling is just an example

Answer (score 0):

That depends a lot, but I honestly prefer in this use case to use it as state in the parent.

Context API, as it says in documentation, was designed for "global" share of data between a tree of react components.  I don't think you should create context just to avoid passing props through components. I'd prefer to rethink component structure to make it possible to do  less props drilling.

Comment: You're misquoting: [Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” **for a tree of React components**](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context). A **tree of React components** is exactly what the OP has. The OPs components in their form makes no sense outside the form "tree" or "context". Rethinking your component structure to avoid context (and avoid prop drilling) will lead to much larger, more complex and difficult to test components. But you are correct in that it does very specifically depend on the exact problem being solved.

Answer (score 0):

Those two blogs from Kent C. Dodds helped me a lot:

- [How to use React Context effectively](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively)
- [How to optimize your context value](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-optimize-your-context-value)

Comment: They're great. I read them a couple of times! Thank you.